# Trigger 404 error if accessed directly

Tags: php, wordpress

I  have a page which basically makes show a information from a specific id through get requests. The url could be something like:

```
http://www.url.dk/kamp/?id=2323
```

I want to redirect to 404 error page, if the page is accessed directly, for instance if you access

```
http://www.url.dk/kamp/
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Why are you using a `GET` request at all then? Why not `POST` the data?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

language?
server?

with apache server and php script, you could do something like:

```
<?php 
if($_GET["id"] === null || $_GET["id"] == false || $_GET["id"] == "")
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
    include("/error_pages/new404.html"); 
}
?>
```

but then you would need a custom 404 page, that can be provided..

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-apache

Comment: Tak Henrik min ven :)

Comment: Ingen årsag ;)
Selvom, det dybest set er ufint at skrive på dansk på et engelsk spørgsmål/svar site.. :p

Comment: Fedt navn kæmpe klunker

Comment: I'm just curious, why did I harvest 3 down votes?
The answer is tested, and works here, so the only reason I can see, is the comment about me not knowing which server or language is used..
and while the tags do mark php, it is not obvious from the title or content..